# How to simplify the output file when a command running

Tags: linux, bash

sometime I will use ">>" to redirect all the output info of a command to a log file,
but I found it's a little inconvenient when checking that log,too much info info
so I wonder if I can just redirect the last line of output info to the log.

if I excute a script like this:
command A
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then 
echo "ok" >> log_file
else
echo "failed" >> log_file
fi
and system halted while A is running,what will I find in the log_file?

Comment: Thank you for all the information you recommend:)(though as a newbie,I can't get the whole meaning of your words)

Comment: apologies; I misread the question and my comment was aimed at a different problem.  I've removed it because it was irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the last line:

```
your_cmd | tail -n 1 >> output_file.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect the last line of output, but you can *check* the last line(s).

```
tail -1 file
```

will give you the last line. If you omit `-1`, the default is `-10` (last 10 lines).

Or you can use `less`:

```
less file
```

and press <kbd>G</kbd> to jump to the bottom of the file.

Oh - and @skjaidev already showed you how to filter the last line into a file.

Answer (score 1):

`tail` is for sure the best thing to do with `-1` option but you can do this with `awk` -

```
…|awk 'END{print NR}' < log.file > new.log.file
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a different way:)

Answer (score 0):

Tr this

```
command | tail -1 >> out_file
```

Comment: Why a negative vote? when i typed the answer there were no answers for this question

Comment: thanks for your help(maybe yours were considered as copying skjaidev's)